# Any idea to using jQuery Mobile RTL?

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

Please don't tell me to use jQuery Mobile RTL plugin...

I want to use the original jquery Mobile, but to tell it - RTL.

Example: http://only4gamer.com/Blader/

Any solution? Something like `data-textalign="right"`?

Thanks You All !

Comment: You can use `text-align:right`

Comment: it's not really helping...

Comment: Have you tried CSS' `direction: rtl;` ? I'm not sure if that's what you want or not

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the reason this plugin exists is that RTL is not built into jQuery Mobile. There is no alternative.

To other commenters:
It's not just about `direction: rtl` and `text-align: right`. When RTLing something you need to flip its entire behavior - e.g. when you click a link, the new link will slide from the LEFT. If the link has the `data-direction=reverse` attribute it will slide from the RIGHT.
Icons need to stick to the opposite side: If your `<a data-role="button" data-icon="home">HOME</a>` link shows a little house on the LEFT in jQM LTR, the little house needs to be on the RIGHT in jQM RTL. If that's done using background-position then that line needs to completely change.

Then there's all the margins and paddings to take care of, and whatever bugs there may be.
For instance, some old browsers don't let you set a background-position relative to the right side of an element.

So we need a more complete solution, which is either the JQM RTL plugin user2900235 didn't want to use or just waiting for jQM to support RTL, which AFAIK it doesn't yet.

Sorry...